# Can I have more than one weapon set?

Tags: diablo-iii

In diablo 2, I could have two sets of weapons equiped and could easily toggle between them with the W key (a dps set and a mf set).

Is it possible to equip multiple sets of weapon in diablo 3, with a key to toggle quickly between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no such option in Diablo III.

(Blizzard decided against it after they found out that during play-testing, players tended to switch to Magic Find gear just before landing the final hit on a boss :)

[source](http://d3db.com/news/id/216-best-buy-developer-qa-transcript/)

Comment: Oh boo, MF gear was the whole point of wanting a 2nd set of weapons! :)

Answer (score -4):

You can set up macros to hot swap gear sets prior to boss kills, chest loots etc.

Comment: How would you go about this?  There is nothing in game to support gear swapping macros.

Comment: I can imagine this being a punishable offense due to the decision to not have this feature in game, so be wary about using anything like this.

Comment: @theorise Just out of curiosity, is there language in the end-user license agreement that forbids this?

Comment: If a Diablo III player is found to be cheating or using hacks, bots, or modifications in any form, then as outlined in the [Diablo III end user license agreement](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/company/legal/d3_eula.html), that player can be permanently banned from the game. This means that the player will be permanently unable to log in to Battle.net® to play Diablo III with his or her account.

Comment: You agree that you will not, under any circumstances: Use cheats, automation software (bots), hacks, or any other unauthorized third-party software designed to modify the Game experience, including without limitation, mods that violate the terms of this License Agreement or the Terms of Use.