# When do I start finding gems?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm about halfway through Act 1, but I haven't found a single gem yet. This seems strange to me since in diablo 2 gems could drop from the very first monster you killed.

At what point do I start getting gems?

Bonus points if you can include why it was changed so monsters don't drop gems from the start :)

Comment: The why part of the question probably can't be answered; it falls into "Why did the devs design it this way?" category.

Comment: @fbueckert Perfectly understandable if the "why" doesn't get answered :) Someone explained why blizzard made a specific design decision in my [other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66813/8462), so figured I'd ask for any insight to this decision too in case anyone knew the answer :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found both my first socketed item and my first gem in Act II after I

> killed Magdha.

However, both [@Sterno](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3062/sterno) and [@OrigamiRobot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/9983/origamirobot) found gems before the activity above - so far, it seems Act II is the only real concrete limitation so far.

However, both [OrigamiRobot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/9983/origamirobot) and [@Resorath](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/4393/resorath) confirm a similar experience (a gem dropping off the activity above). It seems that a gem will always drop from said mob. It does not seem a socketed item drop is guaranteed, though.

It's a few more quests until you find the Jewelry Artisan, Covetous Shen, but it is shortly thereafter in the same Act. You *can* find gems before him, and before the activity above.

Comment: I believe that mob always drops a gem on the first time you kill it.

Comment: Good point - I also suspect that's the case, as an introduction to gems. I'll add to answer - thanks.

Comment: @IanPugsley I found my first in Act II as well, but before the point that you mention (I'm still on my way to find her). My first gem popped out of a chest in a (random?) timed dungeon which I unfortunately forget the name of. I almost missed it since I've grown accustomed to ignoring white items.

Comment: I also found a gem before that event. I was cleaning the town of snakes right before that location when one of the snakes dropped a chipped ruby :)

Answer (score 3):

You start getting gems in Act 2, around the time you meet up with the Jewelry Artisan.  I got my first gems shortly before I met him.

It is likely that this is intentional, as a way of introducing you to the concept in a cohesive fashion (giving you both the gems, and the means of improving and reusing them at roughly the same time).

Comment: One can assume having sockets and gems before introducing him could be very baffling for new-comers.

Comment: @Emerica. It is actually possible, though - I found my first socketed and gem before he was introduced.

Comment: @IanPugsley They must have smelled the blood of Baal and Mephisto on your hands from D2.

Answer (score -1):

I found a gear item with a socket late in act 1 I do believe if not it was right at the start of act 2... still no gems yet and I just made it to iron wolves camp whete theyre locked up.. idk of this helps as its my first time ever playing diablo series.