# Does Diablo have fast gear switching?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I have more than one weapon set?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66810/can-i-have-more-than-one-weapon-set)

Does Diablo 3 have the feature like Diablo 2 did to where you could have two sets of gear built up, and do a fast switch the inventory? I haven't been able to find anything like that anywhere. I find myself teleporting back and forth between the towns and where I am throughout the game to get gear from my stash.

Comment: The only thing you could "fast-switch" in Diablo 2 was the weapon/shield. Not entire gear-sets. Or are you talking about a different feature?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66810/can-i-have-more-than-one-weapon-set)